# Trying to understand Interlocked* functions

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, visual-studio, multicore

This is concerning `Microsoft`/`Visual Studio` and `Intel`/`AMD`-specific implementation only.

Say, if declare a global variable:

```
volatile __declspec(align(16)) ULONG vFlags = 0;
```

And, say, I have multiple contending threads:

```
//Thread 1
ULONG prevFlags;

prevFlags = InterlockedExchange(&vFlags, 0);
if(prevFlags != 0)
{
    //Do work
}
```

and then from other threads, I do:

```
//Thread N
vFlags = SomeNonZeroValue;
```

So say, on a multi-CPU system, at the moment in time while `thread 1` is executing a locked `InterlockedExchange` instruction, some other threads come to executing `vFlags = 2` and `vFlags = 4` instructions.

What would happen in that case? Would `vFlags = 2` and `vFlags = 4` be stalled until `InterlockedExchange` completes, or will it disregard that lock?

Or do I need to use this instead?

```
//Thread N
InterlockedOr(&vFlags, SomeNonZeroValue);
```

Comment: If you don't have memory barriers/synchronisation - threads are not guaranteed to ever see the changes.

Comment: @zerkms can you give more info on what are `memory barriers`?

Comment: http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ and basically good half of articles in that blog is relevant

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks. Nice article. According to it, Microsoft's [Interlocked functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/interlocked-variable-access) implement those fences.

Comment: Interlocked indeed would, but `vFlags = SomeNonZeroValue;` would not.

Comment: @zerkms Even if `vFlags = SomeNonZeroValue;` is called from a different thread? Don't those memory barriers matter for adjacent use of those variables, and otherwise they will get reset during a context switch? Also. I checked and `InterlockedOr` is simply compiled into `lock OR [mem], reg` instruction on an Intel CPU and `InterlockedExchange` into just `XCHG [mem], reg` instruction. Not even with a `lock` prefix.

Comment: Especially because it's run from a different thread. Given `vFlags = SomeNonZeroValue;` comes without memory barriers - it's not guaranteed this change is ever propagated and vice versa. Memory barriers come in pairs on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions that don't use locks to update a variable do not interact with instructions that do. Locking is a cooperative process that all participants must observe in order for it to work. So, yes, updating the flag with a simple assignment on one thread will not be blocked by another thread calling `InterlockedExchange`.

On the other hand, assigning different values to variables that are read by other threads raises the issue of visibility across cores since other threads may not immediately, or indeed ever, see the updates. `InterlockedExchange` solves this issue as well by providing implicit memory fences.

In conclusion, I would use `InterlockedExchange` in all threads updating the flag.

Comment: I'm assuming `InterlockedOr` falls under the same category, correct?

Comment: @MikeF: Yes, in fact MSDN says: `The interlocked functions provide a simple mechanism for synchronizing access to a variable that is shared by multiple threads. This function is atomic with respect to calls to other interlocked functions.`